# Dart: check for updates to a property with reference types

Tags: dart

I understand that dart uses reference types, and I'm wondering if there's a way to declare a variable as a sub-property of a property where modifying that sub-property doesn't propagate back to the original property.

I have a `Foo` class with a property (`bars`) that contains a `List<Bar>`. I have a method (`_getBarListCurrent`) that accepts an instance of `Foo`.

`_getBarListCurrent` is supposed to update the `List<Bar>`, and then pass both the `Foo` and a separate `List<Bar>` to a web service method to update the `Foo` if the list has been changed. So the web service method checks both the solo `List<Bar>` and the list within the foo for equality.

I tried to do this by declaring a variable within `_getBarListCurrent` for `newBars` which is equal to the `List<Bar>` in the `Foo`, then modifying `bars`, and then passing both the `Foo` and `newBars` to the web service.

However, any changes made to `newBars` also get updated in `Foo.bars`, so the equality check in the web service method always returns true, and that method quits without updating the web service.

Is there a way I can declare `newBars` and modify it so I still have an instance of `Foo.bars` that remains unchanged (so I can compare the old and new value before attempting to change the web service)? I've tried declaring the `Foo` again within the method as `originalFoo` but any updates to `newBars` also get updated in `originalFoo` (even if I mark it as final).

Here's how the method looks right now:

```
  Future<Foo> _getBarListCurrent(Foo foo) async {

    List<Bar>? newBars = foo.bars;
    final Foo originalFoo = foo;

    if (x) {
        // add some items to the newBars list
    }

    _fooService.updateBars(foo: originalFoo, bars: newBars);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have to different lists to be able to modify one and not the other.

You can make the copy at whichever point best matches your use-case.

The simple version is to change `Foo` to copy on read:

```dart
class Foo {
  List<Bar>? _bars;
  List<Bar>? get bars {
    var bars = _bars;
    return bars == null ? null : [...bars];
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make the copy where you intend to modify the list:

```dart
Future<Foo> _getBarListCurrent(Foo foo) async {
  var bars = foo.bars;
  List<Bar>? newBars = null ? null : [...bars];
  // ...
```